# A distributional ODE : reference request

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, distribution-theory, greens-function

Is there any solution for this distributional differential equation?

$$y - y'' = \delta(x)$$

Appreciate any references related to this equation.

Comment: inverse laplace transform of $\frac{1}{1-s^2}$?

Comment: Or assume $y$ is a tempered distribution and consider the Fourier transform.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386372/about-peakon-kernel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are, and they are all given by
$$y(x) = \frac12 e^{-|x|} + A e^x + B e^{-x},$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

Comment: Are you sure about second and third terms? Is the exponent in these terms is $x$ or is it $ix$?

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju. Had it been $y+y''$ then it would have been $ix$ instead of $x$.